# vsftpd: user folder on different hard disk

Tags: server, permissions, home-directory, ftp, vsftpd

**The situation:**

Having a secure FTP-server for backing up data. I installed `vsftpd` following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-use-ssl-tls-on-an-ubuntu-vps). It works as expected with TLS.

- vsftpd: version 3.0.2
- Ubuntu version 15.10

The FTP-user named **xxx** has his folder on `/home/xxx/files`.

- The folder `/home/xxx` is owned by `root`.
- The folder `/home/xxx/files` is owned by `xxx` and has read/write permissions.

xxx is able to put files in that folder, so permissions must be set correctly (?)

Here's the output of `sudo ls -la /home/xxx/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 xxx       xxx       4096 Aug 30 17:32 .

drwx------ 4 root      root      4096 Aug 30 17:32 ..

drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx       xxx       4096 Aug 30 17:32 files
```

Here is the content of my `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
```

**The problem:**

As soon as I try to `sudo usermod -d /media/daniel/backups/xxx/files xxx` (moving the user xxx's home folder to another disk) I get the following error:

> Command:  AUTH TLS
>
> Response: 234 Proceed with negotiation.
>
> Status:   Initializing TLS...
>
> Status:   Verifying certificate...
>
> Status:   TLS connection established.
>
> Command:  USER xxx
>
> Response: 331 Please specify the password.
>
> Command:  PASS ******
>
> Error:    GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
>
> Error:    Could not connect to server

What I don't get is that when having the user xxx in his "normal" home folder it works well with TLS.

For testing purposes I connect with FileZilla (3.12.0.2) at the address `127.0.0.1`

**Why do I get this error?**

I googled and tried many things but I don't get to a solution. I also have to say that I'm using linux since 6 months only, so I'm not yet very experienced.

---

**EDIT**

The output of `nmap -A 127.0.0.1` is:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE         VERSION
21/tcp   open  ftp             vsftpd 3.0.2
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=ubuntu
| Not valid before: 2016-05-30T07:15:26+00:00
|_Not valid after:  2026-05-28T07:15:26+00:00
```

Comment: Did you just set the new directory (`usermod -d`) or did you move the old contents into it (`-m`)? What filesystem is on the new disk?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I did with `usermod -d`. There is (yet) no content in that folder. The filesystem is Ext4.

Comment: @steeldriver To be precise the users (xxx) folder is newly created therefore empty, except `.bash_logout`, `.bashrc` and `.profile`

Comment: @steeldriver added `nmap`output